# Using local assets to override gem file assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-engines

I have a rails engine gem that has image_x.jpg in it. I tried to override that image with the one I have locally in my project by adding it to the assets & public directories.

Rails, however, continues to show the image from the gem file rather than my local file.

If I monkeypatch the gem and remove the image image_x.jpg then the image from my local project appears, but this is less than ideal.

Is there a way to tell rails to serve the image from my local project rather than the one in the gem?

In other-words, is there a way to prioritize local assets over the gem file assets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Rails should be using your local image_x.jpg.

To check the order that Rails will search for assets, open your console and type:

`Rails.application.config.assets.paths`

You should be able to verify that your app/assets directory appears before the gem's assets directory in the search PATH. If not, something may be modifying your asset path.

If your asset path looks wrong, you can easily modify it. (It's just an Array of Strings.) To add a new highest-priority directory, try adding something like this to an initializer:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths.unshift "/some/other/path"
```

Also try deleting `tmp/cache/assets` and restarting your server.

Comment: Is there a way to reprioritize the Rails.application.config.assets.paths? Or to add a path at the top, rather than at the bottom?

Comment: Absolutely. It's just an Array of Strings representing directory paths. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Unshift does not seem to work for this. Neither does reversing the array. Reversing the string is the best way I know to explain the issue, lets say the gem adds paths A and B. Then I add paths C and D. Now we have A,B,C,D. When I reverse! I end up getting `A,B,D,C`. So the only paths that it seems I can modify within the array are those added locally, not the ones that were added via the gems. Any ideas on how to fix this? One more thing, I'm adding this line in my `environments/development.rb` config, maybe it's the wrong place?

Comment: Went ahead and sent you the bounty. I haven't solved the problem, but the suggestion to start looking at the `Rails.application.config.assets.path` was very helpful. Thank you for that :) Hope you have more great insight on how to fix what I detailed in the previous comment.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think you want to reverse the entire array. That could potentially impact your application and the gems in unexpected ways. Unshift is the way to go and it worked fine for me when I tested it in the console. I would guess you're having problems because of where you're executing your code in the initialization process. You want it to happen after the gems have performed their configuration. Try moving it into `config/initializers/` and see what happens then.